# GVM and Proxy for class with module system not fully initialized

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I get following error with my application during startup:

Proxy is not supported until module system is fully initialized

I guess the stack trace won't help much?

```
[SUB] java.lang.InternalError: Proxy is not supported until module system is fully initialized
[SUB]   at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.InternalError.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$0(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$$Lambda$1.apply(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at javax.rad.util.EventHandler$ListenerHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at javax.rad.util.EventHandler.setDefaultListener(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at javax.rad.genui.container.AbstractFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at javax.rad.application.genui.UILauncher.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.rad.ui.javafx.impl.JavaFXLauncher.createUILauncher(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.mobilefx.DesktopJavaFXLauncher.createUILauncher(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.rad.ui.javafx.impl.JavaFXLauncher.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.mobilefx.DesktopJavaFXLauncher.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.mobilefx.MobileJavaFXLauncher.<init>(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.mobilefx.MobileJavaFXApplication.createLauncher(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.rad.ui.javafx.impl.JavaFXApplication.start(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sibvisions.mobilefx.MobileJavaFXApplication.start(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$10.run(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$22.run(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
[SUB]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
```

What we doe isn't tricky. We simply create a proxy class for an interface. Should we wait for "initialized" or similar before we start the "app"?

Hm... why is the module system unitialized?

Here's a simple example application, based on Eclipse project template:

```
public class Application extends MobileApplication 
{

    @Override
    public void init() 
    {

        try
        {
            //Runnable is only an example, the problem occurs with any interface
            Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] {Runnable.class}, new InvocationHandler() 
            {           
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable 
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Throwable th)
        {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, BasicView::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene)
    {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);

        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can post some simple code that reproduces your issue, that would help.

Comment: It's better if you edit your question and post it there.

Comment: Any difference if you move the proxy to the `postInit` method?

Comment: Makes no difference!

I tried a loop with this code in a separate Thread, but the VM init level doesn't change. The init states are defined in class: jdk.internal.misc.VM.

Comment: It's not possible to wait. I tried it out and also to set the init state manually via VM.initLevel(2). Seems like a missing initialization step in GVM?

Comment: Do you have any additional tips?

Comment: I didn’t have the time to check it out. Can you file an issue [here](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues)?

Comment: Sure, it's reported.